# why I copy a table and head infomation lost

Tags: javascript

I use JS to copy a table.
The original table html is :

```
<table id="commentTable" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1"  width="95%" align="center" class="ListClass">
      <thead>
        <tr class="ListHeadClass">
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                ID
            </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Name
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>          
      <tbody id="commentBody" class="text11">
            <tr class="ListHeadClass">
                    <td align="center" width="10%">
                        <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                        E00033
                    </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Tom
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>

</table>
```

My Js code is:

```
document.getElementById("signing").innerHTML=window.opener.document.getElementById("commentTable").innerHTML;
```

the result is it displayed the body part but the head part is not. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Do you want to display the table in a div with id of signing? I saw that you set the color for text to white. Try to use a background color to see the text. Try to use only document.getElementById for the right expression without window.opener.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which is the *inner* content of the table.

To get the whole table, including the `table` element, use [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```
document.getElementById("signing").innerHTML=window.opener.document.getElementById("commentTable").outerHTML;
// >>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML =
  document.getElementById("commentTable").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("outer").innerHTML =
  document.getElementById("commentTable").outerHTML;
```

```css
/* Since the table data uses white text */
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Original Table:</div>
<table id="commentTable" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1"  width="95%" align="center" class="ListClass">
      <thead>
        <tr class="ListHeadClass">
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                ID
            </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Name
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>          
      <tbody id="commentBody" class="text11">
            <tr class="ListHeadClass">
                    <td align="center" width="10%">
                        <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                        E00033
                    </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Tom
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>

</table>
<div>Result using <code>innerHTML</code>:</div>
<div id="inner"></div>
<div>Result using <code>outerHTML</code>:</div>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

But you don't need to go through markup (which requires [on getting] that the browser spin through the DOM structure building up an HTML string, and then [on setting] that it parse that string into a DOM structure), you could just copy the elements using [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
document.getElementById("signing").appendChild(
    window.opener.document.getElementById("commentTable").cloneNode(true)
);
```

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("clone").appendChild(
    document.getElementById("commentTable").cloneNode(true)
);
```

```css
/* Since the table data uses white text */
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Original Table:</div>
<table id="commentTable" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1"  width="95%" align="center" class="ListClass">
      <thead>
        <tr class="ListHeadClass">
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                ID
            </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Name
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>          
      <tbody id="commentBody" class="text11">
            <tr class="ListHeadClass">
                    <td align="center" width="10%">
                        <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                        E00033
                    </font>
          </td>
          <td align="center" width="10%">
            <font style="color:#FFFFFF;">
                Tom
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>
                </tbody>

</table>
<div>Result using <code>cloneNode(true)</code>:</div>
<div id="clone"></div>
```

---

Side note: The `font` tag has been deprecated for over a decade. Use a `span` instead (usually with a class so styling is separate from content).